# selecting most recent from each account

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

We have a Model, AccountFeedback, which looks like this

```
class AccountFeedback < ActiveRecord::Base {
                  :id => :integer,
          :account_id => :integer,
            :feedback => :text,
                 :nps => :integer,
          :created_at => :datetime,
          :updated_at => :datetime}
```

I need to do a calculation on the nps field. I need the average nps score. That average should only take into account the most recent AccountFeedback record for each Account, based on the account_id.

So if we have 3 records, two from one account, and 1 from another account, then the average nps should be calculated on 2 records, the most recent from each account based on the created_at field. I also need another variable which is the count of the records included in the calculation.

I have no idea how to start doing the calculation!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this would work for you:

```
vals = feedbacks.group_by {|acc| acc.account_id }.map {|account_id, accounts| accounts.first.nps }
avg = vals.inject{ |sum, el| sum + el }.to_f / vals.size
puts "avg = #{avg}, num_vals = #{vals.size}, vals = #{vals.inspect}"
```

There are probably better ways to do this using some DB tricks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it fairly quickly in the end. It needs refactoring, but this works...

```
    @nps = 0
    @nps_accounts = AccountFeedback.select([:nps, 'MAX(created_at)']).group(:account_id).each do |record|
      @nps += record.nps
    end
    @nps_count = @nps_accounts.count
    @nps = @nps / @nps_accounts.count.to_f
```